# Капча в форме логина Spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

Какие варианты есть валидации капчи в форме логина через Spring? Везде пишут про `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter`, но меня напрягает тот факт что тогда отпадает стандартная форма логина, плюс если переписывать под `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter` не понятно как работать с неправильным паролем, к примеру. Стандартная форма делает редирект с параметром `?error`, а тут просто ошибка выскакивает.

**Убедительная просьба писать примеры конфигурации через java-config, так как иногда он отличается от XML-config.**